# Why is there black residue in my whole house filter?

Tags: plumbing, filter

I recently opened up an old whole house water filter in my basement. The inside walls of the filter are black, but there is no bad smell and the water seems clean (I haven't noticed any problems). Is this normal? I can scrape the black coating off with my fingernail. I'm thinking about cleaning it, but if my filter looks like this I expect the inside of my pipes may as well. Any idea what it could be?

I have attached some pictures. I scraped the inside on one to help show how thing the coating is. It might also be considered a dark brown or green rather than black.

[image: inside of filter]
[image: outside of filter]

Comment: Pictures, please!

Comment: Old filters accumulate whatever they're filtering out; that's their job. I'd be surprised if there wasn't a buildup.

Comment: Water looking clean and not smelling bad does not mean that much.  As with most things, you need testing to tell.  Most filters do need cleaning/replacing every so often.

Comment: If it's a clear housing and the area is not consistently dark, algae is a common issue. You can wrap the outside of a clear housing with foil to block light. But yes, testing the water is needed...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaerobic_corrosion .... "black precipitate of **magnetite** Fe3 O4" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_rust - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetite : "crystallization in an environment containing intermediate levels of oxygen"

Comment: I expect if your pipes are steel and you don't use it much then the insides most certainly *are*. Probably just white scale though as usual. - If you've never had the pleasure of draining a building's sprinkler system that's been in there for 20y, then be thankful it doesn't smell like cat piss (which might've actually been biotic at that point. IDK... it was bad.)

Comment: [How could a black desert form?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/233807/how-could-a-black-desert-form) "Black rust is formed in ... low oxygen environments. That means it is slowly forms under what we would usually consider conditions where rust would not be prone to develop. That makes things tricky. It's considered the "good" kind of rust."

Comment: Anybody do Wiki? Why is there no page for *black rust*.

Comment: I added some pictures to help describe the issue.